# Remove Browser Action Context Menu Default Title Entry

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, browser-action

In my chrome extension I add a couple of entries to the context menu of the browser action.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'browser_action_support',
    title: lang.POPUP.SUPPORT,
    contexts: ['browser_action'],
    onclick: function () {
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': paths.knowledgeBase});
    }
});
```

However there seems to be one entry added automatically at the top. This entry just displays the extensions name defined in the manifest file. In addition this entry is a disabled and won'T do anything on clicking.

[image]

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "__MSG_extName__",
    "short_name": "__MSG_extShortName__",
    "description": "__MSG_extDescription__",
    ...
}
```

However other Extensions like AdBlockPlus have a clickable link at this position. So how can i either make this title clickable with a callback (which then handles the redirect) or remove this entry so i can just insert a link like i do with my other entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to Iváns comment I figured it out.

With the `homepage_url` parameter in the manifest file the context menus title link can be set manually. If the `homepage_url` is not set in the manifest, it will automatically link to the extensions chrome webstore page.

see [Manifest - Homepage Url](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/homepage_url).

Comment: The entry doesn't link to the Web Store, but to the extension's homepage URL, as defined in manifest's `homepage_url` entry.

Comment: Thx for the hint to `homepage_url`. Kinda missed this completly. But if `homepage_url` isn't defined, it will just link to the extension's own page within the chrome webstore. [Manifest - Homepage Url](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/homepage_url)

Comment: @Honkalonkalooooohhh Would you mind editing your answer to include info about the `homepage_url`?